# conditional calculation based on values from another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

They are connected by pkg and Item. This results in the following

[image]

As you can see from the image "Item" has a mix of "BULK" & "PKG" values.

I want to create a new column that uses the cross reference to bring in new values.

The new table I want would look like this

```
 **ITEM**  **Value**   **BULK**  **PKG**   **NEW COLUMN**
  135          2                                 1
  136          4                                 3
  35           1          135       35           1
  36           3          136       36           3
```

The top 2 items on the left are the associated "BULK" values.  I want to bring in the PKG value that appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same `ISBLANK` conditional expression as in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398255/conditional-calculation-based-on-another-column), but use a lookup instead of just `Value`.

```
New Column =
IF(
    ISBLANK( Table1[Bulk] ),
    LOOKUPVALUE( Table1[Value], Table1[BULK], Table1[ITEM] )
    Table1[Value]
)
```

Note that this will throw an error if you have multiple `BULK` values corresponding to a single `ITEM`.